# what occurs when Windows 8 Enterprise evaluation expires?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've been searching to find out what would happen if the evaluation expires before you activate it, but can't find anything except answers to the beta versions with predetermined expirations.

I would like to know what would happen if the actual full version ISO's 90 day trial expired.

When Windows 7 OEM ISOs expired, it just blanked your wallpaper, but otherwise left your system alone.

Will it lock up or do I have to activate it within the time I have remaining?

Thank you for your assistance.